# Sequential connecting points in 2D in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, connect, point, sequential

I was wondering if you could advise me how I can connect several points together exactly one after each other.

Assume:

```
data =
          x        y
      ------------------
      591.2990  532.5188
      597.8405  558.6672
      600.0210  542.3244
      606.5624  566.2938
      612.0136  546.6825
      616.3746  570.6519
      617.4648  580.4575
      619.6453  600.0688
      629.4575  557.5777
      630.5477  584.8156
      630.5477  618.5906
      639.2696  604.4269
      643.6306  638.2019
      646.9013  620.7697
      652.3525  601.1584
```

"data" is coordinate of points.

Now, I would like to connect(plot) first point(1st array) to second point, second point to third point and so on.

Please mind that `plot(data(:,1),data(:,2))` will give me the same result. However, I am looking for a loop which connect (plot) each pair of point per each loop.

For example:

```
data1=data;
figure
scatter(X,Y,'.')
hold on
for i=1:size(data,1)
[Liaa,Locbb] = ismember(data(i,:),data1,'rows');
data1(Locbb,:)=[];

[n,d] = knnsearch(data1,data(i,:),'k',1);
x=[data(i,1) data1(n,1)];
y=[data(i,2) data1(n,2)];
plot(x,y);
end
hold off
```

Although, the proposed loop looks fine, I want a kind of plot which each point connect to maximum 2 other points (as I said like `plot(x,y)`)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all of your helps, finally a solution is found:

```
n=1;
pt1=[data(n,1), data(n,2)];
figure
scatter(data(:,1),data(:,2))
hold on
for i=1:size(data,1)
    if isempty(pt1)~=1
        [Liaa,Locbb] = ismember(pt1(:)',data,'rows');
             if Locbb~=0
                data(Locbb,:)=[];
                [n,d] = knnsearch(data,pt1(:)','k',1);
                x=[pt1(1,1) data(n,1)];
                y=[pt1(1,2) data(n,2)];
                pt1=[data(n,1), data(n,2)];
                plot(x,y);
             end
    end
end
hold off
```

[image]

BTW it is possible to delete the last longest line as it is not related to the question, if someone need it please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use a loop at all.  You can use `interp1`.  Specify your `x` and `y` data points as **control points**.  After, you can specify a finer set of points from the first  `x` value to the last `x` value.  You can specify a `linear` spline as this is what you want to accomplish if the behaviour you want is the same as `plot`.  Assuming that `data` is a 2D matrix as you have shown above, without further ado:

```
%// Get the minimum and maximum x-values
xMin = min(data(:,1));
xMax = max(data(:,1));
N = 3000; % // Specify total number of points

%// Create an array of N points that linearly span from xMin to xMax
%// Make N larger for finer resolution
xPoints = linspace(xMin, xMax, N);

%//Use the data matrix as control points, then xPoints are the values
%//along the x-axis that will help us draw our lines.  yPoints will be
%//the output on the y-axis
yPoints = interp1(data(:,1), data(:,2), xPoints, 'linear');

%// Plot the control points as well as the interpolated points
plot(data(:,1), data(:,2), 'rx', 'MarkerSize', 12);
hold on;
plot(xPoints, yPoints, 'b.');
```

**Warning:** You have two `x` values that map to `630.5477` but produce different `y` values.  If you use `interp1`, this will give you an error, which is why I had to slightly perturb one of the values by a small amount to get this to work.  This should hopefully not be the case when you start using your own data.  This is the plot I get:

[image]

You'll see that there is a huge gap between those two points I talked about.  This is the only limitation to `interp1` as it assumes that the `x` values are strictly monotonically increasing.  As such, you can't have the same two points in your set of `x` values.

Comment: I would appreciate your consideration and time. In fact, the final result looks fine, I need in a loop for further process.

Moreover, that would be great if the polygon could pass through all points even the one has a same 'x' value. 

Thanks again,

Comment: Use a line tracing algorithm: https://github.com/sachinruk/xiaolinwu/blob/master/xiaolinwu.m

Comment: Many thanks @rayryeng. Frankly, I didn't get what it is the line tracing algorithm as its plot result of that is containing just several points.

Comment: The line tracing algorithm is essentially what `interp1` is doing between pairs of points but more robustly.  If you want to connect a **straight line** between two points, you can only do that discretely... basically it will contain several points in between.  I don't know what more you want from your problem.  This'll be my last comment as I think I have resolved the problem.  Good luck.